# Solving $\cos z = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

My attempt:
$$\cos z = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2} = 2 \\e^{2iz} - 4e^{iz} + 1 = 0\\  
e^{iz} = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{12}}{2} = 2 \pm \sqrt{3}.$$
Since the RHS is real, the complex logarithm is equal to the real logarithm, so
$$iz = \ln (2\pm \sqrt{3})$$

Is this correct? I have no solutions so I'd like to confirm. How do I account for periodicity here?

Comment: $\cos z=2$ iff $\cosh iz=2$.

Comment: Would I still have to go through the same process (solving quadratic)?

Comment: Yes, solving a quadratic is necessary.

Comment: I just realised @LordSharktheUnknown's comment might've referred to the periodicity question, but I'm not sure how to use that fact still

Comment: $$e^{iz}=a\implies iz=\ln(a)\pm2\pi ik$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're on the right track.  I would do two additional things.

1)  When you take natural logarithm of complex numbers an additive constant of $i2k\pi$ comes in, as the logarithm is multivalued.  Thus

$iz=\ln (2\pm \sqrt 3)+i2k\pi$

2)  Multiply by $-i$ to isolate $z$.  Note that the numbers $\ln (2\pm \sqrt 3)$ are negatives of each other:

$z=-i \ln (2\pm \sqrt 3)+2k\pi=i\ln (2\mp \sqrt 3)+2k\pi$

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure about the additive constants for some reason. Is it possible for some result to give an odd number of $\pi$? I did a similar question, using same reasoning as you did; but the solution had $(2k+1)\pi$.  
The original question is solving $\cosh z = -5$.

Comment: Indeed you can get an odd number times $\pi$.  The inverse cosine of a negative number $<-1$ does that.

Comment: Hmm, is there a place which shows this? Quite new and want to get the basics down first. I tried solving the quadratic $u^2 + 10u + 1 = 0$ where $u = e^{iz}$, and using the same method, I would have added a multiple of $2\pi i$

Comment: You do indeed add multiples of $2\pi$ for $z$ (meaning, multiples of $i2\pi$ for the full exponent) in your equation.  But all the possible values fold back into one pair of roots when you compute $u=\exp(iz)$.